# How HttpURLConnection get's its inputStream instance?

Tags: java, http, url, inputstream, httpurlconnection

I am curious how HttpURLConnection gets hold of the connection's input stream. I checked the implementation of the parent abstract class URLConnection and found the method

```
 /**
     * Returns an {@code InputStream} for reading data from the resource pointed by
     * this {@code URLConnection}. It throws an UnknownServiceException by
     * default. This method must be overridden by its subclasses.
     *
     * @return the InputStream to read data from.
     * @throws IOException
     *             if no InputStream could be created.
     */
    public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
        throw new UnknownServiceException("Does not support writing to the input stream");
    }
```

1. HttpURLConnection which extends URLConnection doesnt override this method. So was wondering how the inputstream reference is obtained?
2. Something related to this....  When exactly does the http request go to of the client to server? Is it when you call getInputStream() ? or as soon as openConnection() is called?

Thanks in advance
AK

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you print the runtime type of the `HttpURLConnection` object it will be of type `org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl` on Android. That is where your implementation of `getInputStream()` is.

For reference, if you were to print the runtime type of the same object in an Oracle JRE, the runtime type would be `sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection`

Note:
I listed the Android version first because the question was previously tagged as an Android question.

Comment: Thank you Dev. I am using java.net.HttpURLConnection and as you say its the instance of sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.... But I dont see this as something that is included in the Java SDK. Does this need to be imported as external jar? I see that it is part of OpenJDK.  http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/sun/net/www/protocol/http/HttpURLConnection.java

Comment: It's part of the Java JDK, in rt.jar.

Comment: @AKh An implementation will always be provided by the runtime environment.

Comment: I get a compilation error when I do this....
`if(connection instanceof sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection)...`

**Error:**
Incompatible conditional operand types java.net.HttpURLConnection and sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection   --- even though their exist a parent and child relationship

Comment: You shouldn't be testing for sun.* classes as they only exist in Oracle JRE's your code should just use the `java.net.HttpURLConnection` api.